# In a Redis replication setup, how are LRU keys decided?

Tags: redis

In a redis `replication` setup, we have one master and one or more replicas. For the sake of this question, let's say we have `master node M` and `two replica` nodes `R1` and `R2`.

Master node is setup with `eviction policy` as `LRU`.

The question is, how does master know which keys are being least-recently-used on the replica nodes and how does it decide which key to `evict`?

We know reads can happen from both master nodes as well as replica nodes. And my assumption is that eviction happens only on the master node, with master node sending the `DEL` commands whenever a key needs to be expired to the replicas. Let's say there is a key `key1` on `master` as well as `replicas`. `key1` has been accessed on `master` 5 days ago, but on `replicas` it was accessed few minutes ago. Then from master's point of view, will `key1` be considered to be `evicted` because it was accessed 5 days ago? Or the `master` will know that `key1` has been recently access on `replicas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how does master know which keys are being least-recently-used on the replica nodes and how does it decide which key to evict?

Master has no idea on which keys are being least-recently-used on the replica nodes. Master decides the keys to be evicted based on key access info on master node only.

> my assumption is that eviction happens only on the master node, with master node sending the DEL commands whenever a key needs to be expired to the replicas.

Yes.

> Then from master's point of view, will key1 be considered to be evicted because it was accessed 5 days ago? Or the master will know that key1 has been recently access on replicas?

Yes, key1 will be evicted, and master has no idea whether key1 has ever been access on replica.

By default, replica node is readonly, and it does not delete keys expired. Instead, it deletes the key when it receives a `DEL` command from master. If you config replica node as writable, it deletes expired keys based on local key access info (NOTE: this makes master and replica be inconsistent).

Also note that readonly replica node logically evicts expired keys based on local key access info, although it does not physically delete the key.

Comment: Wouldn't this implementation evict the wrong keys? For example, let's say there are 2 keys, k1 and k2. On master node k1 was accessed 5 days ago, but on replica it was accessed just 2 mins back. But for k2, on master it was accessed 3 days ago and on replicas it was not accessed at all. In this case, k1 will be deleted by master, even when it was accessed just minutes ago on replica.

Comment: Yes, this might happen. However, if reads happen on both master and replica nodes, and the key is a *hot* key, this should not be a problem. Since reads should be uniformly distributed on all nodes, and there should be a small gap between the last access time of the key on each nodes. If the key is not *hot*, it might be evicted incorrectly. However, wrongly evict a *cold* key is not a big problem.